# how to insert table into richTextBox with adjustable width and height WPF programmatically

Tags: wpf

How to insert programmatically table into richTextBox with adjustable width and height. WPF? Like Word table.
I put a table in a Rich textbox, but it lasted for the entire window. I would like to be able to adjust the width and height.